# How to reuse adapters between apps

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is it possible to reuse adapters between apps?

The only way I find is to have the adapter with the integration logic to reuse deployed in a specific app and then invoke that adapter from other other HTTP adapter in each App that want to invoke the first adapter. The invocation will be using REST.

Is it possible to do it in a smarter way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapters are per-Worklight project.

As long as your adapters and applications reside under the same Worklight project, your apps could re-use these same adapters.

If your apps belong to different projects, you need to copy them and adjust them accordingly to be used by that project.